# fs readFilesync error path must be a string

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a code for uploading file 
here the code :

```
            var oriPath = JSON.stringify(req.files.profilePicture);
            var data = fs.readFileSync(oriPath.path);
            var ext = path.extname(oriPath.name);
            if (!ext) {
                return next(err);
            }

            var newName = Date.now().toString() + ext;
            var path = config.fullhostname + config.uploadDir + newName;
            if (!fs.writeFileSync(path, data)) {
                return next("Failed to upload image", 400)
            }
```

and showing error like this : `uncaughtException TypeError: path must be a string` refers to `var data = fs.readFileSync(oriPath.path);`

but the file is successfuly uploaded, how to fix that? thank you

Answer (score 1):

try to force string conversion:

```
var data = fs.readFileSync(String(oriPath.path))
```